# left_join except for duplicate columns

Tags: r

I have two datafiles that have overlapping information. One includes estimates, and another includes precise information. I want to combine them into one dataframe, where I keep the estimates if there aren't exact counts, and otherwise replace the estimates with counts if available. How do I left join except where the column names are duplicated?

Dummy data:

```
#df 1
Id = c("1", "2", "3", "4")
Persons = c(300, 400, 200, 5000)
Houses = c(20, 40, 10, 23)
Ages =  c(45, 34, 50, 44)
Races = c(1, 3, 1, 2)

estimates = data.frame(Id, Persons, Houses, Ages, Races)

#df 2
Id = c("1", "2", "3", "4")
Persons = c(321, 421, 198, 4876)
Houses = c(21, 39, 11, 25)

counts = data.frame(Id, Persons, Houses)
```

Target dataframe:

```
  Id Persons Houses Ages Races
1  1     321     21   45     1
2  2     421     39   34     3
3  3     198     11   50     1
4  4    4876     25   44     2
```

Answer (score 2):

```
rows_update(estimates, counts)
```

-output

```
   Id Persons Houses Ages Races
1  1     321     21   45     1
2  2     421     39   34     3
3  3     198     11   50     1
4  4    4876     25   44     2
```